# build failed when using maven call ant tasks "xslt"

Tags: maven-2, ant, maven, maven-3

This part of the pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>                 
                    <executions>
                        <execution>

                            <id>validate</id>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                                <tasks>
                                    <property name="generated.target" value="${basedir}/target/generated" />
                                    <property name="generated.src.test" value="${generated.target}/src/main/java" />
                                    <property name="generated.resources.test" value="${generated.target}/src/main/resources" />
                                    <property name="generated.wsdl.test" value="${generated.resources.test}/" />
                                    <property name="test.resources.dir" location="${basedir}/src/main/resources" />

                                    <mkdir  dir="${generated.resources.test}/wsdl/type_test" />
                                    <xslt classpath="C://saxonhe9-3-0-5j/saxon9he.jar"  style="${test.resources.dir}/wsdl/type_test/type_test_ID_xsd.xsl" in="${test.resources.dir}/wsdl/type_test/type_test.xsd" out="${generated.resources.test}/wsdl/type_test/type_test_1.xsd">
                                          <param name="groupID" expression="1" />
                                    </xslt>
```

...

This is the error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:
run (validate) on project cxf-testutils: An Ant BuildException has occured: java
.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/serializer/ExtendedContentHandler: or
g.apache.xml.serializer.ExtendedContentHandler -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (validate) on project cxf-te
stutils: An Ant BuildException has occured: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/
apache/xml/serializer/ExtendedContentHandler
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
```

I tried add classpath="C://saxonhe9-3-0-5j/saxon9he.jar" in the xslt tag.
But it still throws this exception. I tried Maven 2.2.0 and Maven 3.0.3.JDK 1.6.0 All failed.This pom is actually from apache cxf source code. Anyone can fix it?

**UPDATE**


I tried many workaround. But this one finally works.
Don't change anything in the xslt tag. Just put your xalan jar files into %JAVA-HOME%\jre\lib\endorsed. I download xalan-j_2_7_0. And run cmd 
java  org.apache.xalan.xslt.EnvironmentCheck to ensure it can find it. It finally works. Huh! It costs me hours to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [XML Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/). This supports Saxon virtually out of the box.

Comment: It seems that using apache Xalan brings some jar conflict issue which is really annoying. Anyway, it's still needed.

Comment: It looks like the xml maven plugin is a bit different from ant xslt.

Comment: Does it serve the purpose? If you think you found a bug, file it!

Comment: Not a bug... These questions are actually listed in the Xalan's FAQ.

Comment: One note.It seems the maven-antrun-plugin only supports version 1.6. It's probably the reason why it don't support some new feature in ant.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue,and this is what I did to resolve it.

Add dependency for saxon:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
    <version>9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Add the classpath for saxon:

```
<xslt in="in.xml" out="out.html" style="style.xsl">
  <classpath location="${net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar}" />
  <factory name="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
</xslt>
```